# Template for containers, where is the error?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, containers

I have following code and i want to make a template for the containers size(e.g. vectors, arrays, list etc.)
In the main i define a vector and I call the mysize function from template, but I get an error: "see declaration of mysize". Can somebody help??

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename I, typename Op>
Op mysize(I first, I last)
{
    auto it = 0;
    while (first != last) {
        ++first;
        it += 1;
    }
    return it;
}

void  main()
{

    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    auto _begin = v.begin();
    auto _end = v.end();

    auto result = mysize(_begin, _end);

}
```

Comment: `void main()` is not good, this is c++ - it should be `int main()`.

Comment: How is it supposed to guess what type you mean for `Op`?

Comment: That is not the error. That is a trailing part of the error. What is the error?

Answer (score 6):

The `Op` type cannot be deduced.

This should work:

```
template <typename I, typename Op = std::size_t>
Op mysize(I first, I last)
{
    auto it = 0;
    while (first != last) {
        ++first;
        it += 1;
    }
    return it;
}
```

Or:

```
template <typename I>
std::size_t mysize(I first, I last)
{
    std::size_t it = 0;
    while (first != last) {
        ++first;
        ++it;
    }
    return it;
}
```

Or:

```
template <typename I>
std::size_t mysize(I first, I last)
{
    return std::distance(first, last);
}
```

Comment: or specify template parameters when mysize is called?

Comment: I believe `std::ptrdiff_t` would be a more appropriate type in this case.